# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ,Getting error like this

Tags: ios, swift4

My requirement : I will be having a list of chat details in a table view.On top of table view ,there will be a search functionality using text field.based on unique id of user, search should get done.if there is no chat with the unique id, which the user entered,then it has to redirect to another screen which is called chatcreatepage. when ever we are searching chat, we will be using an api called FIND API and in that FIND API there is a chat dictionary,if it is null,then create chat will get called.If that chat dictionary is not nil then need to display that chat details in chat list table view. When the chat list page is loading then ,we will be calling Chat list Api.when we are searching the chat by entering the unique id in textfield,we will be getting the corresponding details of that entered unique id & that unique id details we have to show in the table view.

This is the task and i have done till the chat list showing in the table.FIND  API Integration is also done.When i am reloading the data with search result(find api response),I am getting fatal error like "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at the line of "var recepient = dict["recipient"] as! [String:Any]" . If anyone helps me to solve it, would be really great.Thank in advance.I am providing the code below.

```
    import UIKit
        import Alamofire
        import SwiftyJSON
        import SDWebImage
        class ChatlistViewController: UIViewController{
             var pro = [[String:Any]]()
             var dict:[String:Any]!
             var idd = ""
             var id = ""
            var chatt:Dictionary = [String:Any]()
            var searchActive : Bool = false
            var filtered:[String] = []
            var data:[String] = []

            @IBOutlet weak var searchtext: UITextField!
            @IBOutlet weak var chatlisttable: UITableView!
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                       apicall()

            }



            func apicall(){

                let acce:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-tokenn")!
                        print(acce)

                        let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(acce)","Content-Type":"application/X-Access-Token"]

                Alamofire.request(Constants.Chatlist, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        print(response)
                        if response.result.value != nil{
                            var maindictionary = NSDictionary()
                            maindictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                            print(maindictionary)

                            var userdata = NSDictionary()
                            userdata = maindictionary.value(forKey: "data") as! NSDictionary

                            var productsdetails = [[String:Any]]()
                            productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as! [[String:Any]]
                            self.pro = productsdetails
                                 print(self.pro)
                                   self.chatlisttable.reloadData()

                        }else{
                            let Alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No data found ", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                            Alertcontroller.addAction(CancelAction)
                            self.present(Alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                                break
                            case .failure(let error):

                                print(error)
                            }
                        }


            }

            func searchapicall(){
                idd = searchtext.text!
               let acce:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access-tokenn")!
                print(acce)

                let headers:HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"Bearer \(acce)","Content-Type":"application/X-Access-Token"]
                print((Constants.Chatlistsearch)+(idd))
                Alamofire.request((Constants.Chatlistsearch+idd), method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {  response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success:
                        //print(response)
                        if response.result.value != nil{
                            var maindictionary = NSDictionary()
                            maindictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary

                            var chat:Dictionary = maindictionary.value(forKey: "data") as! [String:Any]

                            var chattt:Dictionary = chat["chat"] as! [String:Any]

                            if (chattt != nil) {

                               // print("Find Action")

                                self.chatt = chat["user"] as! [String:Any]
                                print(self.chatt)
                                self.pro = [self.chatt]
                               // print(self.pro)
                             self.chatlisttable.reloadData()

                            }else{
                                let viewc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController") as? ChatViewController
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewc!, animated: true)
                            }

                        }else{
                            let Alertcontroller = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No data found on this unique id", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let CancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                            Alertcontroller.addAction(CancelAction)
                            self.present(Alertcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):

                        print(error)
                    }
                }

            }




        }


        extension ChatlistViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

            func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

                self.searchapicall()

                return true
            }

        }

        extension ChatlistViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                if (searchActive == false){
                return self.pro.count
                }else{
                    return 1
                }
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                var cell = chatlisttable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatlistTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatlistTableViewCell

                if (searchActive == false){

                dict = pro[indexPath.row]
                var recepient = dict["recipient"] as! [String:Any]
                print(recepient)

                var name = recepient["name"] as! String
                print(name)
                id = recepient["unique_id"] as! String
                print(id)
                var image = recepient["avatar"] as! String
                print(image)
                cell.namelbl.text = name
                cell.idlbl.text = id
                cell.imageView!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:image), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Mahi.png"))

                }else{

                    cell.namelbl.text = chatt["name"] as! String
                    cell.idlbl.text = chatt["unique_id"] as! String
                }

                return cell
               self.chatlisttable.reloadData()

            }

        }

    //Response format

    {
        "success": 1,
        "status": 200,
        "data": {
            "user": {
                "id": 3,
                "unique_id": "10002",
                "name": "nani",
                "avatar": "https://www.planetzoom.co.in/storage/user/avatar/AkgcUFF3QIejMhZuLF4OXnSFHjxNAOo4FuXV3Mgi.jpeg"
            },
            "chat": null
        }
    }


//Response with chat dictionary data

{
    "success": 1,
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 8,
            "unique_id": "10007",
            "name": "Mahitha",
            "avatar": "https://www.planetzoom.co.in/storage/user/avatar/cZt9yQlBzIEewOdQ1lYZhl3dFiOv2k3bxG7HLOzR.jpeg"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 4,
            "status": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-02-27 12:26:24",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-27 12:26:24"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to provide two feedback to you:

1. Please try to make a habit to avoid `forced casting` or `forced unwrap` how much ever is possible.
2. Use Camel Case Naming Convention

So, you can change

```
var recepient = dict["recipient"] as! [String:Any]
```

to

```
 guard let recepient = dict["recipient"] as? [String:Any] else {return cell}
```

Similar way you can have a condition before loading the tableView

```
if let productsDetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as? [[String:Any]] {
    // write code 
} else {
    // write code to handle else
}
```

Comment: When i used this guard statement ,i am getting an error "Non-void function should return a value"

Comment: Oh Sorry you need to return cell.

Answer (score 1):

You should update you code to get chat details as follow due to I have seen `chat` in nil in your response

```
if var productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as? [[String:Any]] {
    // Code to display chat
} else {
    // Code to display nil error
}
```

I hope this will fix you issue.

Comment: now can you please check the code.I have updated something with response.and the thing is"if var productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as? [[String:Any]] {
    // Code to display chat
} else {
    // Code to display nil error
}
"Here I am getting response.when ever chat dictionary is nil then it will redirect to some other page.if not nil, then the table should get reload with the searched result(find api response)

Answer (score 1):

From your response chat is null. So `productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as! [[String:Any]]` you are doing like that, you have set a null value in userdefaults across the key 'chat', and you are retrieving the null value as `[[String : Any]]`

So you have to check this using the block

```
if let productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as? [[String:Any]] {
    // write code that for chat
} else {
    // write code for chat is null 
}
```

This is called `Optional Chaining`, you may find this [link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)

> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties, methods, and subscripts on an optional that might currently be nil. If the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call succeeds; if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript call returns nil. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

Or you may solve using `guard` statement

```
guard let productsdetails = userdata.value(forKey: "chat") as? [[String:Any]] else {
    // write code for chat is null 
    return 
}

\\ write code that for chat
\\ you can use productsdetails variable here
```